# Q#: Error on dotnet run: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (5): Access is denied

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code, q#

I tried to install Q# a few days ago using the instructions listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/learn/modules/qsharp-create-first-quantum-development-kit/2-install-quantum-development-kit-code), but unfortunately, when I try to run the example program using the command `dotnet run`, it returns an error. Maybe I just did something wrong, but I feel like I read the instructions a number of times now. It could have something to do with "Win32" in the error message, as I have a 64 Bit system? As far as I can tell, I installed the x64 version of all the packages. As you may notice, I am a newbie to .NET and Q#. Maybe someone knows how to fix this. Thank you in advance!

Code:

```
namespace QH {
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Canon;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Intrinsic;
    

    @EntryPoint()
    operation SayHello() : Unit {
        Message("Hello quantum world!");
    }
}
```

Terminal:

```
PS C:\Users\User\Documents\Q#\QH> dotnet run
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (5): Zugriff verweigert
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils.Command.Execute(Action`1 processStarted)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils.Command.Execute()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Run.RunCommand.Execute()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Run.RunCommand.Run(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.ProcessArgs(String[] args, ITelemetry telemetryClient)
```

What I tried:

- Restarting computer
- Reinstalling dotnet
- Installing latest version of git because Visual Studio Code told me to
- New project in another path
- Start VS Code as admin
- run in command line (`dotnet run --project C:\Users\User\Documents\Q#\QH`) - it returned the same error
- several other minor things

Comment: Have you tried to run i t as administrator?

Comment: @JairoBlancoAldao Yes

Answer (score 0):

You need something like a Python file to run the code.

```
import qsharp
from QH import SayHello
SayHello.simulate()
```

Than run the Python file not the QH.qs file

Comment: I tried this first by installing the qsharp library for python via pip, but it did not work and gave the following output when run (the python script):`IQ# is not installed. Please follow the instructions at https://aka.ms/qdk-install/python.
Traceback (most recent call last):
... jupyter_client.kernelspec.NoSuchKernel: No such kernel named iqsharp
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
... qsharp.clients.IQSharpNotInstalledError: IQ# is not installed.
Please follow the instructions at https://aka.ms/qdk-install/python.`

Comment: I then followed the instruction from the link. I executed these commands in anaconda: `conda create -n qsharp-env -c quantum-engineering qsharp notebook`, `conda activate qsharp-env` and then executed the python file from there using `python C:\Users\User\Documents\Q#\QH\start.py` but the following error occurs: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Q#\QH\start.py", line 2, in <module>
    from QH import SayHello
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'QH'`
I tried changing the import in the python script to `Program.qs`, `Program` and `QH.csproj`, same result

Comment: start.py is in the same folder as the Program.qs and QH.csproj files, and I feel like python cant import them because they are not written in python. However, I could be getting something completely wrong here. Thanks for the help!

Comment: By the way, I forgot to mention, in the example project I am using, Program.qs contains the code I posted in the question and QH.csproj contains this: `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.Quantum.Sdk/0.14.2011120240">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
`

Comment: As I started I had the same error [Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Q#\QH\start.py", line 2, in <module>     from QH import SayHello ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'QH']...I can´t explain why but I fixed it with the changing the name of the namespace in HelloQuantum

Comment: hmm, that changed nothing for me.

Comment: I just use the filename1.py and the filename2.qs file. I checked your code and it is exactly the same as mine. If you have 2 files with the name "QH" than is there an ImportError. I´ve never seen someone using a .csproj file so try it without this file... maybe this will fix it.